# Django: ImproperlyConfigured error when running unit test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm trying to write my first unit test in Django (running 1.5). It's a simple test to see if the home page returns a 200 Status. The code is in a file `tests.py` in one of my apps. The file looks like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client

class HomePageTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.c = Client()

    def test_anonymous_home_page(self):
        """Test the home page when visited anonymously"""

        response = self.c.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

When I run the `manage.py test app_name.HomePageTestCase` command, I get the following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_anonymous_home_page (project.my_app.tests.HomePageTestCase)
Test the home page when visited anonymously
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../project/my_app/tests.py", line 12, in test_anonymous_home_page
    response = self.c.get('/')
  File "/Applications/djangostack-1.5.1-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 453, in get
    response = super(Client, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-1.5.1-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 279, in get
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-1.5.1-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 406, in request
    response = self.handler(environ)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-1.5.1-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 102, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Applications/djangostack-1.5.1-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 53, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware middleware: "No module named middleware"

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas how I might fix this? Thanks in advance.

## Edit 1:

Middleware from `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'johnny.middleware.LocalStoreClearMiddleware',
    'johnny.middleware.QueryCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'middleware.CustomMiddleware',
)
```

Relavent apps from `settings.py` file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',

...
)
```

## Edit 2:

After commenting `'middleware.CustomMiddleware',` out from `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` I get a new error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_anonymous_home_page (project.my_app.tests.HomePageTestCase)
Test the home page when visited anonymously
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../project/my_app/tests.py", line 11, in test_anonymous_home_page
    response = c.get('/')
  File "/Applications/djangostack-1.5.1-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 453, in get
    response = super(Client, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-1.5.1-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 279, in get
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-1.5.1-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 424, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-1.5.1-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 103, in get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-1.5.1-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 321, in resolve
    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-1.5.1-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 223, in resolve
    return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-1.5.1-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 230, in callback
    self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-1.5.1-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 31, in wrapper
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Applications/djangostack-1.5.1-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 101, in get_callable
    not module_has_submodule(import_module(parentmod), submod)):
  File "/Applications/djangostack-1.5.1-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named my_app

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It looks like it might be a python path problem or something? I'm no expert in it, that's for sure.

## Edit 3:

File structure looks roughly like this:

```
.
├── project
│   ├── email
│   │   └── management
│   │       └── commands
│   ├── app_name
│   │   ├── api
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   └── test.py
│   ├── library
│   │   └── templatetags
│   ├── sitemaps
│   │   ├── exports
│   │   └── management
│   │       └── commands
│   ├── app_name_2
│   │   ├── api
│   │   ├── management
│   │   │   └── commands
│   │   └── migrations
│   ├── templates
│   └── app_name_3
│       ├── api
│       └── migrations
└── manage.py
```

Comment: What's going on in your settings file in the middleware section?

Comment: Just added an edit with middleware and installed apps.

Comment: Do you have a file middleware.py with a class CustomMiddleware in your app directory?

Comment: So the web app can find middleware.py in the project directory. I wonder why it can't resolve it when running as a unit test?

Comment: Can you post your project structure?

Comment: @cezar: There is a file `middleware.py` with CustomMiddleware in it. This hasn't been a problem until now (it's almost 6 months old), so it's a little confusing. I commented this out of `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and I get a new error (seemingly passing the first now). I'll post another edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the path to the project wasn't in the system paths. So I added this to the top of the test file:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/the/way/to/the/project')
```

Feels a little hacky but... it works! I'm sure there's a file structure issue at the route of it.